# Combine OneDrive and OnDrive for Business accounts to one client

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have a personal OneDrive account, that syncs with the OneDrive client that came on the laptop. I recently synced a work OneDrive for Business account to the same machine. I now have two clients running.
[image]

The properties and tray icon to the left are for personal account, the ones on the right are business account. As you can see there does not appear to be any difference in the clients.

Everything seems to be working fine, but I'd like to run both through the one client, if possible. Is it?
Do I add the personal account to the for Business client and disable the personal client, or vice versa?

PS: Bonus question; the personal account appears to be working fine, but the tray icon is gone grey - any idea what this signifies here?

Comment: "Is it?" - No;  However, I see 2 tray icons, in your screenshot.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned, since syncing the second account there now appears to be two clients running - I'd like to reduce that to one if possible.